# Azure AD: Create user with extra identities

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having trouble creating a user in an Azure Active Directory with a custom identity. The body of my request looks like this:

```
{
   "passwordProfile": {
     "password": "password-value"
   }, 
   "accountEnabled": true, 
   "displayName": "FIRSTNAME LASTNAME", 
   "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration", 
   "creationType": "LocalAccount", 
   "identities": [
     {
       "issuerAssignedId": "avalid@email.com", 
       "signInType": "emailAddress", 
       "issuer": "my_tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
     }
   ]
 }
```

I've also tried a version of the request where I specify `mailNickname` and `userPrincipalName`. In every case, the creation fails with the error:

```
{
   "error": {
     "innerError": {
       "date": "2020-02-20T17:23:48", 
       "request-id": "c5a7c8da-35bd-4ae2-9ae8-6714b672f035"
     }, 
     "message": "One or more properties contains invalid values.", 
     "code": "Request_BadRequest"
   }
}
```

There's a [code snippet](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/includes/snippets/csharp/create-user-from-users-identities-csharp-snippets.md) in the C# docs that suggests this should be possible.

What am I missing?

Comment: which API version you are using? It looks like your sample is using a beta version...

Comment: I'm using `v1.0`. I'm making a `POST` request to: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Microsoft Graph allows you to [manage user accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api) in your Azure AD B2C directory by providing create, read, update, and delete methods in the Microsoft Graph API. You can migrate an existing user store to an Azure AD B2C tenant and perform other user account management operations by calling the Microsoft Graph API.

If you try to use this Azure AD Graph API request for a normal Azure AD tenant, it will get the same error massage as yours.

So, **ensure the tenant you're trying to query is a B2C tenant**.

Try to use the global admin of the [B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant) (e.g. username@b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com) to obtain a token. Then use the token in the head to use the API :
Request:

```
 POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version=1.6
```

Body Content-Type: application/json:

```
{
   "passwordProfile": {
     "password": "password-value"
   }, 
   "accountEnabled": true, 
   "displayName": "FIRSTNAME LASTNAME",
   "mailNickname": "mspcai", 
   "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration", 
   "creationType": "LocalAccount", 
   "identities": [
     {
       "issuerAssignedId": "avalid@email.com", 
       "signInType": "emailAddress", 
       "issuer": "my_tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are referring to a *beta* snippet, please try the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users
```

Comment: I get exactly the same error using the `beta` API. Request-id: `104216df-55a7-42d5-ab2a-6dd8bd5578fe`